# Block position element doesn't work in chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I'm a beginner in CSS and I'm trying to make absolute position menu. It works fine in firefox, but in chrome, I have to refresh the page to make it works.

www.gadgetcote.com/bangda

This is the CSS for header and content wrapper:

```
#headerWrapper{
    display:block;
    height:150px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top:20px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:999999;
    background:url(../images/body-bg.png) no-repeat center top #0066ff;
}

#contentWrapper{
    margin-top: 125px;
    padding-bottom:32px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

If I open it in chrome, it doesn't show the right display. Anyone have any idea about this or how to do this correctly ? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the position problem.

```
position:fixed;
```

Can you give me a link to your site? I'm not able to figure out the problem. I need to check the html and full css code.

Comment: Hi Libin. Im so sorry for the late reply. Have been away for a few days. This is the link www.gadgetcote.com/bangda

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need a fixed menu bar like twitter. Just use twitter bootstrap to achieve this.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#navigation Its simple to use. The fixed menu is inbuilt in it. Also you will get a good and standard style to your website. Use the CSS link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css">
```

or download the bootstrap.css file and use it. And you don't need to worry about the CSS !

Answer (score 0):

"but in chrome, I have to refresh the page to make it works."

Just throwing this out there that Chrome likes to store the CSS in it's cache. In that case, refreshing the page or clearing the cache (Tools > Clear Browsing Data > Empty the Cache) will fix it.